# Cannot change anything in chart options

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I have a bar chart and I would like to change the font color, border width and some other tings, but it doesn't work. It is in my computed property. In the chartOptions I want to change the y axis min and max value but I don't know if it is correct. Can anyone help me?

Also I want to make a horizontal line in this bar chart. It is the "Enemy's Avarage" and now it is a constant. I set the type to line and now I have a dot in my chart.

This is my chart component:

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { Bar } from 'vue3-chart-v2'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ChanceChart',
  extends: Bar,
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    chartOptions: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
    },
  },
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions)
  }
})
</script>
```

And this is my app:

```
<template>
    <div id="chart">
      <ChanceChart :chartData="chartData" :chartOptions="chartOptions" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation.vue";
import ChanceChart from "../components/ChanceChart.vue";
import PageLoader from "../components/PageLoader.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    ChanceChart,
  },

  computed: {
    chartOptions() {
      return {
        options: {
          scales: {
            y: {
              title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Value'
              },
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            ticks: {
              stepSize: 10,
            }
            },
          },
          elements: {
          point: {
            radius: 0
          },
          line: {
            borderWidth: 2
          }
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 0,
              font: {
                fontColor: "#fff",
                color: "#fff"
              },
            },
          },
        },
        }
      }
    },
    chartData() {
      return {
        datasets: [
          {
            type: 'bar',
            label: "Enemy's Chance",
            borderColor: "#1161ed",
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: this.emnemyCardsFilled,
          },
          {
            type: 'bar',
            label: "My Chance",
            borderColor: "#f87979",
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: this.myCardsFilled,
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            label: "Enemy's Avarage",
            borderColor: "rgb(238, 255, 0)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            data: [50],
          },
        ],
      }
    },
    
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the options part in the computed chartOptions prop:

```js
chartOptions() {
  return {
    scales: {
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Value'
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 10,
        }
      },
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      },
      line: {
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        labels: {
          boxWidth: 0,
          font: {
            fontColor: "#fff",
            color: "#fff"
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
},
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem :/